# Copying BIND9 authentication files to new machine

Tags: ubuntu-server, bind

I've recently got my first BIND server up & running, and one of the first things I did after getting it working was to copy some of the configuration files to my virtual machine.

EDIT: These servers will never run in parallel. I only run the virtual server when I am booted into Windows, so I want them to appear identical. They have the same MAC addresses, IP addresses and hostnames.

I have a static IPv6 address and a legit DNS name, and am afraid that the second BIND server I configured will never be trusted by any other DNS client / resolver or server.

What files would I need to copy over from the trusted server to the machine seen as a man-in-the-middle?

I plan on reading [this O'Reilly chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/dns4/chapter/ch11.html), but it looks far too heavy for this moment in time...

In my case, both machines are running Ubuntu Server, and the latest BIND9 releases from the main apt repositories.

UPDATE: Having copied everything in /etc/bind/ from the properly authenticating machine (Virtual machine) to the other (physical) partition, I am still getting issues with dynamic dns updates for ipv6 clients. 
The server is running a Teredo IPv6 tunneling interface (tspc) and the router advertisement daemon (radvd) to advertise the IPv6 tunnel to other machines on my network. To illustrate it's potential whilst demonstrating the problem, on a Windows client:-

```
 > ipconfig /renew
 Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix   .  : example.com
     IPv6 address.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  : 2001:<48bits>::random64bits   <From Server>
     Temporary IPv6 Address  .  .  .  .  : 2001:<48bits>::2ndrandom64bits<also from server>
     Link-Local IPv6 Address .  .  .  .  : fe80::<64bits>%10
     Ipv4 Address 
  .... 
 Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface: 

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix   .  : 2001: completely random 112 bits 
     Link-local IPv6 Address .  .  .  .  : fe80::another random address 
     Default gateway   .  .  .  .  .  .  : 

 Tunnel adapter isatap.example.com:

     Media State .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  : Media disconnected
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix   .  : example.com
```

And when I run that `ipconfig /renew` command on the windows client, I then see this error in the bind server log:-

> 05-Aug-2011 22:21:14.946 update-security: error: client fe80::<Link-local IPv6 address>%2#57124: view internal-view: update 'example.com/IN' denied

This looks like a misconfiguration, but I never saw this error on the virtual machine. The update restrictions I have in place for the view and forward zone in question are:-
`allow-update { key "rndc-key"; };`
When using rndc-key, I have to create a key file in /var/cache/bind/ i.e.:-
`touch /var/cache/bind/<reallylongnumber>.mkeys`;
 otherwise I get a 'file not found' error in the bind log. Essentially, I copy the file name I see in the error log, that named says it can't find, and just create an empty file. 
I haven't yet checked whether these file names in /var/cache/bind are the same on both the physical and virtual machine. I'm pretty sure it was empty on the virtual machine though too, although don't know whether the name is randomly generated (and then cached) or not... 
So I am wondering whether there is some other cache somewhere (I've looked in /var/cache and /var/run) that stores some other information relating to these rndc-keys or perhaps something else (machine ssl certificate?). 
Otherwise, could it be a problem with the client not trusting the server? Having double checked, the MAC addresses are not identical between the virtual server and physical machine. Could this seem like a compromised system to a client? Should I just change the host name but keep the same IP address to keep DNS resolving? 
Also perhaps of use, I found this BIND option today - `multi-master yes ;` although I imagine it's directed for master's running simultaneously.. 
Any thoughts on the easiest (and best) option? Any and all suggestions welcomed gratefully...

Answer (score 1):

Per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto

In order to make a backup of your BIND configuration, make a backup of the **/etc/bind** as it looks like the Ubuntu port drops everything in that directory.

Comment: Copying the zone files and bind config will not work as the 2nd server has to be a slave server and not a master as the 1st is and the configuration is different.

Comment: I was not suggesting that, I was just suggesting what to backup ;-)

Comment: @Astron. I've sync'd the named.conf and db.* files, which are in /etc/bind, but nothing like the rndc-key or any other identifier / encryption key. Thanks for the link. I was hoping for a brief answer that would save me from reading reams of documentation...

Comment: @Laurent. No, I both want them to appear as master for the zone, as I don't run them at the same time. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: ok - @astron: I will only be able to remove the downvote if you edit your answer.

Comment: @laurent I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your second server has to host slave zones and not master. Only the 1st server can be master for the zone (SOA). You need to configure the 2nd as a slave and let it receive the zones records from the master, not copying the zone files.
Anyways, you need two public IPs to put 2 servers online.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. The two BIND servers don't ever run at the same time. I only run the virtual machine when I'm booted into windows, so my two bind servers do have the same IP address, and I want them to appear identical to any client or forwarder.

Comment: ok - sorry. To do so, you will also need to copy the zone files at every modification (and keep the serial numbers identicals).

Comment: To tie any loose ends; I've just booted the physical machine for first time in a while. It was this bind server which was giving auth issues, so I've been fine-tuning the virtual server, and I've been away, hence my delay.
I've copied everything in /etc/bind/ from the virtual machine to the physical partition now (of course with a back-up), but I think there must be some other cache on either this machine or my laptop, as my laptop fails to authenticate with dynamic dns (IPv6). Will need the space above, so I'll modify my question with a fuller update...